# Mapping type which includes a typesafe transformation function

Tags: typescript

Apologies if this has been asked before; I feel like I've done my homework here but I can't find what I'm after.

I'm trying to re-map an interface *and* allow consumers to provide transformation logic in a type-safe way:

```
interface A {
  first: {
    value?: 'Yes' | 'No'
  };
  second: {
    value?: number
  };
}

interface B {
  foo?: boolean;
  bar?: string;
}

type MapItem<TKey extends keyof B> = {
  key: TKey;
  transform: ((value: unknown) => Exclude<B[TKey], undefined> | null);
};

// consumer code:

const mapping: Record<keyof A, MapItem<keyof B /* this feels incorrect! */>> = {
  first: {
    key: 'foo',
    transform: (value) => typeof value === 'string'
     ? value === 'Yes'
     : null
  },
  second: {
    key: 'bar',
    // I want this to give a type error, because it returns a boolean
    // rather than a string!
    // Instead, the function type is inferred as (unknown) => boolean | string | null
    transform: (value) => typeof value === 'number'
     ? value >= 10
     : null
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for you help, I hope I've been clear in what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your `MapItem` definition is that it merges the **transform**   function return type because it cannot infer that the `TKey` is a specific `TKey`.

What you need to do is to infer the TKey so that Typescript knows that you're referring to a specific instance of TKey, once inferred Typescript loses track of the information that the inferred key was an actual key of B so that's why we have to add once again the check.

With that in mind the `MapItem` definition is changed to the following

```
type MapItem<TKey extends keyof B> = TKey extends infer ITKey 
    ? ITKey extends keyof B
        ?   {
                key: ITKey;
                transform: ((value: unknown) => Exclude<B[ITKey], undefined> | null);
            }
        : never
    : never;
```

After this change, you can see now that the key second shows an error

```
 Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnJsKAZzAC5MddkA3OAGwFcIB+MgcgE0JDXkAfZVgDkA9qwoBfANwVCEBMJAATMtkrU6jFshD0AtgCNoE6eKxZQkWIhQAhcrhjDhW-U9oQ4Iabn1woW4ihQAHMTMzAATwAHFABZOCiASUhdAB4AFQBpCAjkCAAPSCVCZABrHOEYZBsAPmQAXmQsnLzCiGLkUBhoZETm3IpcJl7+1qLFEvKIyurBtWRh3FV5lbUpsj7siO9V3bAoT0JHKF0yAAozmgYIMnoQUpBhAHcQAEoGuoBRfIQGRQhUjYANqbHIAXQANMg7v98CAIIo6vwdLRaK8drtcKZdmR4VQjGpcRB8VBpFgAPTk5DyECEPQ9eT-EhmGnEZC6BJREJkABKcmEUEUqSmM1QUPiSRSwoqVTs5IAVMgwAALYAlboQWglUDyKBQORgACEyHl5JqdUay3wRFI9ko6wEjlEELm+0Ox1OyEuGgg73qdUiMRmV0YDXqjVYgRCYnmwxDKHDEc43DmyFx9FREhduFkNOUdtwDtYvigrGzlEpvWQT08YCVqpKYGEyGCwHxyDgSuiKGgUAFUMMCDg9FknTr+rA9CgtI7yFcwncnjmlYOKp6Ks8s6jIGChuXVMStMgcEUULXeDuCDAwAUXZinW1IG6eoRHZKZzuD2ebw+c7cHhAPhkG3YIgJRWhXQOWkPXOeM-QDbtgx9MMIx0AxoBjNQ42QmpGgARgABlTdNMyxLBTCAA)